# PL/SQL delete static workspace file

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I've been searching on google and still not found anything.

Is there any possible way to delete a file from the Static Workspace Files within the database?

For example you can remove a file from the Static Application Files with this procedure `wwv_flow_api.remove_app_static_file`

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for app 4000 page 315 (the page used to delete a static workspace file through the APEX Builder), it doesn't seem to be using any sort of API to remove the file.  It just seems to be performing a DELETE on **WWV_FLOW_COMPANY_STATIC_FILES**. You should be able to perform the DELETE yourself if you prepend your APEX schema to the beginning of the table like this:

```
DELETE FROM APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_COMPANY_STATIC_FILES
      WHERE id IN (SELECT workspace_file_id
                     FROM apex_workspace_static_files
                    WHERE workspace = 'MY WORKSPACE' AND file_name = 'temp.txt');
```